# Administrate gem install forcing me to use Kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, will-paginate, kaminari

After adding the gem and running rails g administrate:install I go to localhost:3000/admin and find that my app crashes with error NoMethodError - undefined method `per' for #Asset::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007faef5b99820

I figured that this is because administrate gem has Kaminari dependency and  I use will_paginate gem in my app.

Kaminari and will_paginate do not work together. More in here > https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/162

I fix the issue by replacing will_paginate with Kaminari in my GEMFILE and app is running again. However I would like to use will_paginate gem in my app.

Is there an easy way to scope or limit the Kaminari gem just to be used /admin or to be used just by administrate gem? If I need to write lot of iniliazer scopes like it seems its not wort of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Administrate uses kaminari, if you want to use something else then either choose a different admin toolkit, or fork the Administrate gem and make the necessary code/dependency changes so that it works with the different pager you want to use.

Comment: Thought as much. Still I was hoping there be some "magic trick" I could use.

Comment: Anyway its good to leave this question here as it took me some time to figure why this error was happening.